# Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel query result is difference from downloaded XLS

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-query-builder, maatwebsite-excel

I have a query for attendance for the last 5 days which includes the employee Id, their name, Date and the time the logged in and out.

If I run the query in MySql, it returns the correct date but when I use the Maatwebsite/Laravel excel it seems like it is missing some records.

I tried doing some research but I cannot find a way to determine what's causing it.

```
return $user = DB::table('users AS u')
   ->join('user_attendance AS a', function($join)
       {
        $join->on('u.user_id', '=', 'a.user_id')
        ->whereBetween('a.server_time', ["2019-10-01 00:00:00", "2019-10-15 23:59:59"]);
       })
       ->select('u.user_id', 'u.username',
                DB::raw(
                    'min(case when a.action = "IN" then date(a.server_time) end) `Date`,
                     min(case when a.action = "IN" then time(a.server_time) end) `IN`,
                     min(case when a.action = "OUT" then time(a.server_time) end) `OUT`'
                    )
                )
       ->groupBy('u.user_id', 'u.username', DB::raw('Date(a.server_time)'))
       ->orderBy('u.user_id')
       ->orderBy(DB::raw('Date(a.server_time)'))
       ->get();
```

Result in Mysql if I run this query shown below

```
| EmployeeId | EmployeeName |     Date    |     IN    |   OUT    |  
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  400442    |     Pooh     |  2019-10-02 |  08:49:02 | 18:08:00 |
|  400442    |     Pooh     |  2019-10-07 |  08:29:22 | 18:08:35 |
|  400442    |     Pooh     |  2019-10-09 |  08:36:41 | 23:28:52 |
|  400442    |     Pooh     |  2019-10-10 |  08:20:15 | 21:40:12 |
|  400442    |     Pooh     |  2019-10-15 |  08:47:13 | 20:57:05 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I run the code in Laravel with the use of MaatWebsite/Laravel-Excel it returns incomplete date.
Here's my code's

AutomailerController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\UsersExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use DB;

class AutomailerController extends Controller
{
   use Exportable;

    public function export() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new UserLogs, 'users.xlsx');
    }
}
```

And here's my UserLogs.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use DB;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {


        return $user = DB::table('users AS u')
                       ->join('user_attendance AS a', function($join)
                           {
                            $join->on('u.user_id', '=', 'a.user_id')
                            ->whereBetween('a.server_time', ["2019-10-01 00:00:00", "2019-10-15 23:59:59"]);
                           })
                           ->select('u.user_id', 'u.username',
                                    DB::raw(
                                        'min(case when a.action = "IN" then date(a.server_time) end) `Date`,
                                         min(case when a.action = "IN" then time(a.server_time) end) `IN`,
                                         min(case when a.action = "OUT" then time(a.server_time) end) `OUT`'
                                        )
                                    )
                           ->groupBy('u.user_id', 'u.username', DB::raw('Date(a.server_time)'))
                           ->orderBy('u.user_id')
                           ->orderBy(DB::raw('Date(a.server_time)'))
                           ->get();
    }
}
```

If I call it via Router using browser it will download a file but the file will be like the one shown below, Incomplete data

```
| EmployeeId | EmployeeName |     Date    |     IN    |   OUT    |  
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  400442    |     Pooh     |             |           | 22:28:52 |
|  400442    |     Pooh     |  2019-10-10 |  08:20:15 | 21:40:12 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm expecting it to be the same result when I run it on Mysql.

Is there something happening on the backend which I missed?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

On the documentation, says that don'y put get, maybe thats the mistake.
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-query.html